# Building Shared library including Qt libs via QMake on Windows

Tags: windows, qt, dll, qmake

I would like to create a Dll on Windows using QMake+mingw, which includes some custom widgets and the dependent Qt libraries (linked into one library). Can this be achieved via QMake?

What I have tried so far:

Creating shared library project, and adding LIBS to .pro file:

```
QT       += widgets
TARGET = testqtdll
TEMPLATE = lib
DEFINES += TESTQTDLL_LIBRARY
SOURCES += testqtdll.cpp widget.cpp
HEADERS += testqtdll.h testqtdll_global.h widget.h
FORMS += widget.ui
LIBS += -lqt5core -lqt5gui -lqt5widgets
```

This way the resulting dll does not include QT libs.

Creating static library project, and link qt static libs. Then create dll after:

```
QT       += widgets    
TARGET = testqtlib
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += staticlib    
SOURCES += testqtlib.cpp widget.cpp
HEADERS += testqtlib.h widget.h
FORMS += widget.ui
LIBS += c:/Qt/Static/5.3.1/lib/Qt5Core.a
LIBS += c:/Qt/Static/5.3.1/lib/Qt5Gui.a 
LIBS += c:/Qt/Static/5.3.1/lib/Qt5Widgets.a
```

This way the resulting lib also does not include QT libs.

Comment: on your shared library project case, you should also link static libraries like you did below.

Comment: Not working, they are not added to the linker call

Comment: can you post dependency walker snapshot of the `testqtdll`? We need to see the effective linkage of the resulting library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution after all. One should use the Qt static build to create such dll. Working project file:

```
QT       += core gui widgets
CONFIG += static dll
TARGET = testqtdll
TEMPLATE = lib
DEFINES += TESTQTDLL_LIBRARY
SOURCES += testqtdll.cpp widget.cpp
HEADERS += testqtdll.h testqtdll_global.h widget.h
FORMS += widget.ui
```